# TypeError: Expected container to be an Element, a Document or a DocumentFragment but got string

Tags: react-testing-library

I'm trying to run the below testcase using RTL , and the test is failing with the error "TypeError: Expected container to be an Element, a Document or a DocumentFragment but got string.". I tried searching for solution but couldn't find one .

```
describe("Feedback Commponent",()=>{
  it('should throw error when feedback textbox is empty', () => {
    const { getByLabelText} = render(<Contact />);

    fireEvent.change(getByLabelText('Feedback'), {
      target: { value: '' },
    });

    fireEvent.blur(getByLabelText('Feedback'));
    debug();

    expect(getByTestId('feedback-error')).toBe(
      'Please Enter Your Feedback'
    );
  });
});
```

The above snippet is suppose to test the feedback form , to be specific only the feedback text box , when it is empty and when user goes out of focus from the textbox ,there should be an error stating "Please Enter Your Feedback".

Answer (score 30):

It seems that you imported getByTestId method straight from testing library instead of destructuring it from render like you did with getByLabelText.  getByTestId, according to the docs is:

```
getByTestId(
  // If you're using `screen`, then skip the container argument:
  container: HTMLElement,
  text: TextMatch,
  options?: {
    exact?: boolean = true,
    normalizer?: NormalizerFn,
  }): HTMLElement
```

So it expects the first argument to be the HTML container, hence the error.
One solution would be to destructure getByTestId as well:

```
const { getByLabelText, getByTestId } = render(<Contact />);
```

Another one is to use screen, as suggested by the docs:

```
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';
...

expect(screen.getByTestId('feedback-error')).toBe(
  'Please Enter Your Feedback'
);
```

In which case the first 'container' argument is skipped and the string 'feedback-error' is treated like test id 'text' argument. Docs:
https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue by changing the assertion to

```
expect(getByText('Please Enter Your Feedback')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

from

```
 expect(getByTestId('feedback-error')).toBe('Please Enter Your Feedback');
```

Also I noticed that I had setupTest.js file with

`import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';`

missing , which  adds custom  jest matchers for asserting on DOM nodes, so after adding the above changes my test case passed